# On the homotopy type of $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^3)$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am confused with the following argument. I know I am doing something wrong but I can't find my mistake.
On one hand, one knows that if $M$ is a Lie group, then
$$\mathrm{Diff}(M)\simeq M\times\mathrm{Diff}(M, \mathrm{rel}\,x_0),$$ where $x_0$ is the identity element in $M$. One way to check this is considering the fibration $\mathrm{Diff}(M)\rightarrow M$ that maps $\phi$ to $\phi(x_0)$. Then the fiber is $\mathrm{Diff}(M, \mathrm{rel}\,x_0)$. In order to check the fibration is trivial, one can find a global section in a straightforward way by using the lie group structure of $M$.

Thus, if we particularize $M=\mathbb{S}^3$ we get that 
$$\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^3)\simeq\mathbb{S}^3\times \mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^3, \mathrm{rel}\,x_0)$$
whereas we know by Hatcher's theorem that $$\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb{S}^3)\simeq O(4).$$ What am I missing? I will appreciate any comment or suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would there be a contradiction? You also have a fiber bundle $O(3) \to O(4) \to S^3$ and it's trivial for similar reasons. So already you know $O(4) \simeq S^3 \times O(3)$. I'm not an expert, but why wouldn't it be true that $\operatorname{Diff}(S^3,x_0) \simeq O(3)$?

Comment: What is the problem? The conclusion from your argument should be that Diff(S^3relx_0) should have the homotopy type of O(3). I’m afraid that product structures are not compatible with homotopy equivalences, so you can not conclude that O(4) is a product S^3xO(3).

Comment: I was thinking that $Diff(\mathbb{S}^3 rel x_0)$ was homotopy equivalent to $Diff(\mathbb{D}^3, rel \partial)$, which has the homotopy type of a point. Therefore I concluded that $O(4)$ should be h.e. to $\mathbb{S}^3$, which is clearly not true.  Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There is a further fibration still, whose projection is $\text{Diff}(S^3, x_0) \to GL(T_{x_0} S^3)$. The fiber is homotopy equivalent to the diffeomorphisms of the disc rel boundary.

Comment: @Mike Miller yes, thank you very much for the nice observation.